# Clicking a button and getting the input from a user

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: ThePicture]

Here is a picture. I have done css and html on my own and now don't know how to add javascript here.
What I want is:

1. a user writes something
2. then he clicks on button (for example uppercase) and his text appears at the bottom, instead of words "Here will be you text". How can I add such a function? I am confused.

Comment: Can you post the code you've written so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of ***onclick***, ***toUpperCase*** and ***toLowerCase*** can be used to obtain the required result.

**Here is a working example:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h2>Write something</h2>
  <input id="inputText" type="text" placeholder="write something" style="width: 300px;">
  <br>
  <button onclick="upperCaseButtonClicked()">Upper case</button>
  <button onclick="lowerCaseButtonClicked()">Lower case</button>
  <button onclick="doNothingButtonClicked()">Do nothing</button>
  <br>
  <textarea id="outputArea" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea>
  <script>
    function upperCaseButtonClicked() {
      var input = document.getElementById("inputText").value
      var output = input.toUpperCase()
      document.getElementById("outputArea").innerHTML = input.toUpperCase()
    }

    function lowerCaseButtonClicked() {
      var input = document.getElementById("inputText").value
      var output = input.toUpperCase()
      document.getElementById("outputArea").innerHTML = input.toLowerCase()
    }

    function doNothingButtonClicked() {
      var input = document.getElementById("inputText").value
      document.getElementById("outputArea").innerHTML = input
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in pure Javascript, you can do the code in the snippet.

I will assume that you know HTML and CSS, end explains only the javascript code.

The idea is:

1. You attach an event listener to handle de user click in each button. Each button has it's own class name, you can use it as a parameter of the document.getElementsByClassName to get an array of objects with this class name. Next you attach the event handler, you can do this with addEventListener.
2. Inside the click event function, you put the action that will be triggered after any click at the button.

The snippet below has commented code to clear things.

```js
//Get input field with text before any operation
var textField = document.getElementsByClassName("text-field")[0];

//Get button that will trigger the Upper Case function
var upperBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("to-upper-btn")[0];

//Get button that will trigger the Lower Case function
var lowerBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("to-lower-btn")[0];

//Get div that will show the result
var resultContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("text-result")[0];

//Attach a click event listener to the Upper Case button
upperBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){

  //Set the inner html of the result container with te value of the input field in uppercase;
  resultContainer.innerHTML  = textField.value.toUpperCase();
  
});

//Attach a click event listener to the Lower Case button
document.getElementsByClassName("to-lower-btn")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){

  //Set the inner html of the result container with te value of the input field in lowecase;
  resultContainer.innerHTML  = textField.value.toLowerCase();
  
});
```

```css
.text-field {
  width:300px;
}

.container {
  margin-top:50px;
  border:1px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-radius:5px; 
  background:#000;
  color:#FFF;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Write something</h1>
<input type="text" class="text-field"/>
<button type="button" class="to-upper-btn">To Upper Case</button>
<button type="button" class="to-lower-btn">To Lower Case</button>

<div class="container"> 
  <div class="text-result">Just write what you want to make Upper Case or Lower Case, the result will be displayer here</div>
</div>
```

For more details about the javascript methods used in this code:

[getElementByClassName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

[addEventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp)

[toUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

[toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest form, using jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#uppercase-btn').click(function() {
        $('#myoutput').val($("#textid").val().toUpperCase());
    });

    $('#lowercase-btn').click(function() {
        $('#myoutput').val($("#textid").val().toLowerCase());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="myinput" id="textid" /> 
<button id="uppercase-btn">Uppercase</button> 
<button id="lowercase-btn">lowercase</button>
<textarea id="myoutput" disabled></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const nameNode = document.getElementById("Name");
const nameCopyNode = document.getElementById("NameCopy");
if(nameNode){
  nameNode.addEventListener('input',function(){
    if(nameCopyNode){
      nameCopyNode.value = this.value
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<input type = "text" placeholder = "type your name" id="Name"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type = "text" placeholder = "you are typing" disabled id="NameCopy"/>
```